# jqplot: two y axis (decimal & percentage) for line chart

Tags: jqplot

Is it possible for jqplot to have two y axis for one series in line chart: one for decimal values another for percentages?

Here is my code. There are two lines and their values are in percentages. I need to show two y-axis.

```
var irr1 = [['2008-09-30', -100], ['2008-10-30', -99.81], ['2008-11-30', -95.73],
                    ['2008-12-30', -80.28], ['2009-01-30', -56.67], ['2009-02-28', -41.54],
                    ['2009-03-30', -30.33], ['2009-04-30', -23.31], ['2009-05-30', -19.93],
                    ['2009-06-30', -8.57], ['2009-07-30', 0.14], ['2009-08-30', 11.24], ['2009-09-30', 20.35]];
        var irr2 = [['2008-09-30', -100], ['2008-10-30', -99.10], ['2008-11-30', -86.44], ['2008-12-30', -60.00], ['2009-01-30', -34.43],
            ['2009-02-28', -20.80], ['2009-03-30', -12.54], ['2009-04-30', -7.88], ['2009-05-30', -5.52],
            ['2009-06-30', -0.96], ['2009-07-30', 2.09], ['2009-08-30', 5.47], ['2009-09-30', 7.92]];

        var data = [irr1, irr2];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot(elem.attr('id'), data, {
            animate: true,
            grid: {
                backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                gridLineColor: '#000000',
                drawBorder: false,
                shadow: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0.5
            },
            //title: 'Default Date Axis',
            seriesDefaults: {
                rendererOptions: {
                    //////
                    // Turn on line smoothing.  By default, a constrained cubic spline
                    // interpolation algorithm is used which will not overshoot or
                    // undershoot any data points.
                    //////
                    smooth: true
                }
            },
            legend: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                show: true,
                location: 'n',
                placement: 'outsideGrid',
                //shrinkGrid: true,
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 1
                }
            },
            //legend: {
            //    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
            //    show: true,
            //    rendererOptions: {
            //        numberRows: 1
            //    }
            //},
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '%Y-%m-%d' },
                    min: '2008-09-01',
                    tickInterval: '1 month'
                }
            },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }],
            series: [
                        { label: 'IRR' },
                        { label: 'MIRR' }
                    ],
        });
```

Comment: if i understand it correctly, do you want your `irr1` on `yaxis` and `irr2` on `y2axis`?

Comment: No, I want irr1 and irr2 to have the same yaxis, but with different units. One y-axis will show Percentage (for example, 10, 20 etc.), but second y-axis will show the same values, but decimal like (0.1, 0.2).

So, probably, I have to create irr1, irr2 and irr1_decimal, irr2_decimal, is it true?

Comment: correct. that way you can make one go with y1 and other go with y2.